# TypeScript Arrow functions and Decorators

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to workout whether its possible to decorate an arrow function in TypeScript like this example:

```js
function decorateThisFunction() {        
    return (target: any, propertyKey: any, descriptor?: any) => {        
        console.log("This is my decorator do bar!");
    }
}

@decorateThisFunction
export const foo = (): void => {
    console.log("My Arrow Function");
};
```

If this isn't possible is there any alternative approaches people recommend?

Comment: It's not possible, only if that function is a member of a class

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the official docs:

> A Decorator is a special kind of declaration that can be attached to a
> [class declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), [method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators), [accessor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators), [property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), or [parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators).

So if you need a decorator you have to attach it to a class:

```
function decorateThisFunction(target: any, propertyKey: any, descriptor?: any): void {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        console.log("This is my decorator do bar!");
        originalMethod(...args);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    @decorateThisFunction
    static foo(): void {
        console.log("My Arrow Function");
    }
}

SomeClass.foo();
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTgJwIZVQFQAsYBnAMXGnjAAoptMBzVKALkWzAE8AaRAB0xx+qTFC4BpVF3adeKVCQiYY-KFgD8s7gEp2ANzgxkiAN4BYAFCIbiDGBJREWGIxhhsAGwCyLQnBMAXgUlFTUsADp9LxBUAG4rWxDlVXVMKJjURGDQSFgERBoI4oZGEm0uAG0AXR0zRKTbexI4T1QIzzhGGgAiIlJEAYBbLgUMHDSUOEQAIwYAQh6dBOtGmxc3Dx8-AKKSphJlhpsAXyszyysIT2wSEkQAZTgh1ABhG7v61ZsAATRx3AEYjkSj5MDHRCOXAwCCIYBwOA0PSIQzGL5rGzNVrtTrdHreUYAQUwQgA7ogKHlqEsVkkLhcrE8Xu9biQIvDEcsgA)

Without using a class you could simply use higher order functions:

```
function decorateThisFunction(func: (...args: any[]) => any) {
    return function(...args: any[]) {
        console.log("This is my decorator do bar!");
        func(...args);
    }
}

export const foo = decorateThisFunction((): void => {
    console.log("My Arrow Function");
});

foo();
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&preserveWatchOutput=false&pretty=false&ssl=12&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTgJwIZVQFQAsYBnAMXGnjAApRIAuRGgOje0wHMSnswBPANoBdAJSIAvAD5EffuIDeAWABQidYkyooITEnpUErdlx6yBIxao03EGMCTgAbVCydxONAERFSiPwC2-CjoWLhYKHCIAEYcAIReogDc1rbqBsYsHNzJqeoAvqqFKqqoAB4ADlhQdggkNcBwURIhGDh4vuSUsEY0okwAbnAwyJIyymoa9o4ubh7eALLBAIKYmHAA7ogUkD1giSkq%20bklKo1wfUlAA)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: A `static` method in a class is not a convenient alternative?

Comment: Without using a class

Comment: E.g. `const foo = () => {}`

Comment: Without using a class, I suggest to simply use higher order functions

Comment: thanks, ill check them out

Comment: How might I use a higher order function for this task?

Comment: By declaring it and using it like I did in my answer. Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: Perfect thanks dude